# How does `npm cache verify` garbage collection work?

Tags: npm

According to the [npm-cache docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-cache): `npm cache verify` does this:

> Verify the contents of the cache folder, **garbage collecting any unneeded data**, and verifying the integrity of the cache index and all cached data.

How does npm determine what is garbage-collectable or unneeded?

For example, I have a CI job that shares an npm cache with multiple package projects. I want the cache to contain the dependencies for all of them. But I'm worried that if a certain package doesn't hit the cache every so often, the dependency might get garbage-collected. I want to minimize cache thrashing.